# AngularJS Original ngClick method is called even after binding click to another method

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to override ng-click on a button with in my link attribute of my directive.  Problem is, when I click on the button, my method is called right after which the original method registered with ng-click is called.

I tried Priority, but it didn't work. Please help me on overriding the original click.

This is my directive:

```
mainModule.directive('sessionTimeoutCheck', function () {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    restrict: 'AEC',
    template: '',
    scope: false,
    controller: SessionTimeoutController,
    link : function(scope,element,attr){
        scope.dataObj = element.attr('data-ng-click');
        element.bind("click", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            scope.canSubmitAngularForm(element, event);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

and my HTML is:

```
 <button session-timeout-check data-ng-if="button.type == 'button'" 
       data-ng-disabled="!!button.disableOnInvalid && form.$invalid || button.disable && button.disable()" 
       class="btn btn-info" data-ng-click="button.click($event)" 
       data-i18n-content="button.label | call" 
       data-ng-attr-qa-name="button-{{button.name}}" 
       class="btn btn-info">
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this working for you ?

```
mainModule.directive('sessionTimeoutCheck', function () {
   return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      replace: true,
      scope: false,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.submit = function(){
            //// logic here
            console.log("submit from link");
            scope.functionInController(); // it call the "functionInController" in the parent controller
         };
      },
      template: ""
   }
});
```

html

```
<button session-timeout-check
    class="btn btn-info" ng-click="submit()"
    class="btn btn-info">submit 
</button>
```

I Edited my answer. 
Your directory herit the scope of the controller where it's called and all the fonctions inside it scope. hope it help a little.